# io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Could not convert arguments...It appears you did not register a data table type

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber

the feature file:
Feature: Cucumber can convert a Gherkin table to to a map.
Scenario: An international coffee shop must handle currencies
Given the price list for an international coffee shop

```
  | product | currency | price |
  | coffee  | EUR      | 1     |
  | donut   | SEK      | 18    |
```

When I buy 1 coffee and 1 donut
Then should I pay 1 EUR and 18 SEK
there is a part of the code:

```
@Given("^the price list for an international coffee shop$")
public void the_price_list_for_an_international_coffee_shop(List<Price> prices) throws Throwable {
    priceList = new HashMap<String, Price>();

    for (Price price : prices) {
        String key = price.getProduct();
        priceList.put(key, price);
    }
}
```

> io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Could not convert arguments
>   for step [^the price list for an international coffee shop$] defined at
>   'hellocucumber.StepDefs_PriceList.the_price_list_for_an_international_coffee_shop(java.util.List)'.
>   It appears you did not register a data table type. The details are in the
>   stacktrace below.
>
> ```
>     <cucumber.version>5.4.1</cucumber.version>
>     <junit.version>4.13</junit.version>
> ```

I'm a junior in cucumber. Could you please explain what exactly needs to be changed in the code?
It looks like this error is because of the new cucumber version 5 but it's very unclear how to make it work.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're upgrading from v1.x to v5.x.

In v1.x Cucumber would automatically convert data tables into POJOs. This was handled internally by XStream. Unfortunately this resulted in a close coupling between Cucumber and XStream.

Instead, if you want to convert data tables into POJOs you now have to provide your own object mapper. You can register one for all transformations like so:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JSR310Module;
import io.cucumber.java.DefaultDataTableCellTransformer;
import io.cucumber.java.DefaultDataTableEntryTransformer;
import io.cucumber.java.DefaultParameterTransformer;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class StepDefinitions {

private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = 
   new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JSR310Module());

    @DefaultParameterTransformer
    @DefaultDataTableEntryTransformer
    @DefaultDataTableCellTransformer
    public Object defaultTransformer(Object fromValue, Type toValueType) {
        JavaType javaType = objectMapper.constructType(toValueType);
        return objectMapper.convertValue(fromValue, javaType);
    }
}
```

Note: We're using `jackson-databind` in this example. It doesn't work exactly the same way Cucumbers integration with XStream did but it should suffice for most use cases.

You can also a data table transform for a specific java type:

```
Given some authors
   | name            | first publication |
   | Aspiring Author |                   |
   | Ancient Author  | [blank]           |
```

```java
package com.example.app;

import io.cucumber.java.DataTableType;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;

import java.util.List;

public class StepDefinitions {

    @DataTableType(replaceWithEmptyString = "[blank]")
    public Author convert(Map<String, String> entry){
      return new Author(
         entry.get("name"),
         entry.get("first publication")
      );
    }

    @Given("some authors")
    public void given_some_authors(List<Author> authors){
      // authors = [Author(name="Aspiring Author", firstPublication=null), 
      //              Author(name="Ancient Author", firstPublication=)]
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that JSR310Module was replaced by JavaTimeModule since Jackson 2.7